# Javascript put first row in thead

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible using javascript to move the first row as follows into a `<thead>` tag?

```
<table id="TBL1399802283490" class="confluenceTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th class="confluenceTh" style="cursor: pointer;">Server Name  </th>
      <th class="confluenceTh" title="null" style="cursor: pointer;">Network Zone  </th>
      <th class="confluenceTh" title="null" style="cursor: pointer;">Operational Status  </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="confluenceTd"><div style="left:1em;right:1em"> w264521f </div>  </td>
      <td class="confluenceTd"><div style="left:1em;right:1em"> GREEN </div>  </td>
      <td class="confluenceTd"><div style="left:1em;right:1em"> READY </div>  </td>        
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Which becomes

```
<table id="TBL1399802283490" class="confluenceTable">
  <thead>
      <tr>
      <th class="confluenceTh" style="cursor: pointer;">Server Name  </th>
      <th class="confluenceTh" title="null" style="cursor: pointer;">Network Zone  </th>
      <th class="confluenceTh" title="null" style="cursor: pointer;">Operational Status  </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>        
    <tr>
      <td class="confluenceTd"><div style="left:1em;right:1em"> w264521f </div>  </td>
      <td class="confluenceTd"><div style="left:1em;right:1em"> GREEN </div>  </td>
      <td class="confluenceTd"><div style="left:1em;right:1em"> READY </div>  </td>        
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm not too familiar with Javascript, so any help is much appreciated!

Comment: how do you generate the table ?

Comment: use clone() to copy the content from one place to another.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for the table given in your code, for a general table it's better to obtain the elements in more secure way.

```
var table = document.getElementById('TBL1399802283490');
var thead = document.createElement('THEAD');
var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName('TBODY')[0];
var tr = table.getElementsByTagName('TR')[0];

table.appendChild(thead);
tbody.removeChild(tr);
thead.appendChild(tr);
```